# PHP e Wordpress, executar um script toda vez que fazer uma nova postagem

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá, eu estou precisando de que toda vez que eu fazer uma nova postagem em Wordpress executar um *script*. Não quero perder tempo fazendo aplicativos, apenas quero saber qual é a página responsável para enviar os *posts* no Wordpress. Quero saber também se é possível pegar o `Título da postagem` para passar como parâmetro toda vez que tiver uma nova postagem.

Como faço isto de maneira rápida?

O motivo disto? Preciso executar um *script* que eu mesmo fiz para enviar notificações *push*. Apenas preciso toda vez que fizer uma nova postagem executar o script com `Título da postagem`.

Se puder me ajudar; agradeço, obrigado.

[EDIT]
Descobri o nome do arquivo do Wordpress, se chama post.php e fica na pasta wp-admin, agora preciso saber aonde eu coloco o script de enviar e-mails e como eu pego o titulo da postagem no post.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize esta função para retornar um valor `booleano`:

```
function is_edit_page($new_edit = null){
    global $pagenow;
    //certifique-se de que estamos no backend
    if (!is_admin()) return false;


    if($new_edit == "edit")

        return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php',  ) );

    elseif($new_edit == "new") //check for new post page
        return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post-new.php' ) );

    else // verifica se há é uma nova postagem ou foi editada
        return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) );
}
```

### Agora utilizaremos as condicionais para validar:

```
if (is_edit_page()){
   //sim, é uma edição ou nova página de postagem
}
```

Checando se é uma nova postagem(AQUI FICARIA O SEU SCRIPT DE E-MAIL)

```
if (is_edit_page('new')){
   //sim é uma nova postagem

}
```

Checando se foi somente editada:

```
if (is_edit_page('edit')){
   //sim é uma nova postagem
}
```

[Leia mais...](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50043/how-to-determine-whether-we-are-in-add-new-page-post-cpt-or-in-edit-page-post-cp?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Entendi, mas em que lugar eu coloco este código. seria no post.php? Ou em uma página diferente? Estou começando em WordPress, isto deve ser executado toda vez que eu fizer uma postagem nova. Tenho que mandar para o servidor a PUSH notification com as informações da nova postagem.

Comment: A função fica no `functions.php` e a as condições no arquivo `post.php`.

Comment: Entendi, está funcionando corretamente. Se eu mudar de tema pode dar problema na hora de executar o post.php? Tem como fazer isto diretamente pelo meu tema? Ou seja, mudar o post.php somente quando estiver usando aquele tema.